# How create valueless column In Cassandra By CQLEngine

Tags: python, django, cql

I have a question about how I can Create valueless column in Cassandra by CQLEngine. I mean I want store information in column name instead of column value for some purpose.
But in CqlEngine you should define you column name before you run your project in model file.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Django does not support Cassandra, I think. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Brainiac , Django support cassandra by to driver : pycassa and cqlengine . They are so strong too. you can search it on google

Comment: No, what I meant is that you don't have ready-made models given to you by django like you do with postgres or mysql.

Comment: yes, you are right. but in my project I need to have cassandra  as my database and I have many problems with these library (pycassa and cqlengine), thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

What your asking about would traditionally be accomplished using the Thrift api and wide rows, defining your own column names.  This is not how CQL3 works.  If you want to work this way, you can use pycassa, or you can create columns with compound keys.

For example, with CQL3:

`create table ratings 
( user_id uuid, item_id uuid, 
rating int,
primary key (user_id, item_id));`

You'd actually create a wide row, with user_id as the key, and the columns would have the item_id, and the rating would be the value.  With compound primary keys, rows are transposed  into columns.

You might want to read this: http://brianoneill.blogspot.com/2012/09/composite-keys-connecting-dots-between.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. The article was so useful , but let me ask you you It means that it is not possible in CQL3 to define a column name by programmer ?? in your example the column name is defined by two UUID fields that will be generated automatically by system, so how can I have slice query ( query over some column for example comment0 to comment999 ) when I don't know the column names??

Comment: I found it.I can do it by create two primary key or more in my CF.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first I need to define my column family like this:
    create table test(
    user text,
    itemLiked text,
    primary key (user,itemLiked))

so the user is row key and itemLiked is Clustering key.
If I insert values to this cf , cassanndra doesn't create row (internally) for that
and the itemliked value will be the name of columns
    insert into test(user , itemLiked) values ( "user1","Item1");
    insert into test(user , itemLiked) values ( "user1","Item1");

So cassandra will create two column with name Item1 and Item2 for rowkey user1
this columns hav not any values and as described in this article:
   http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html
in line that:
**Moreover, a table must define at least one column that is not part of the PRIMARY KEY as a row exists in Cassandra only if it contains at least one value for one such column.**